# The meaning of "stood it out, visibly yellowing,"

Tags: meaning

> We booked our berths, and when the time came, he wafted us and ours
> aboard the Southampton mail-boat with the pomp of plenipotentiaries
> and the precision of the Navy. Then he dismissed his yacht, and became
> an inconspicuous passenger in a cabin opposite to mine, on the port
> side. We ran at once into early British spring weather, followed by
> sou’west gales. Mrs. Godfrey, Milly, and the nurses disappeared.
> **Attley stood it out, visibly yellowing**, till the next meal, and followed suit, and Shend and I had the little table all to
> ourselves.

This is from "The Dog Hervey " by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-dog-hervey.htm

What does "stood it out, visibly yellowing" mean in this context?

Answer (score 2):

The passage is describing unpleasant weather at sea. "Early British spring weather, followed by southwest gales" does not make for a pleasant and calm voyage; instead there would be much rocking of the ship. Passengers who were not accustomed to this would become very seasick.

Based on the context of "next meal" and "little table," Kipling is using the dining room to demonstrate the illness of the other passengers. Seasick people are nauseous and do not want to eat anything, so it makes sense that they would "disappear" from the dining table; likely they remained in their rooms and did not come out to eat.

*Stood it out* means *endured it.* *Yellowing* is the present participle of the verb *to yellow*, that is, to become yellow in color, with "visibly" modifying it. So: Attley *endured the seasick-causing conditions, while turning yellow from the seasickness*, until the next meal; then he also stopped coming.

The "yellow" describes Attley's face; seasickness and other illness can result in people's faces turning pale and sometimes other colors. Usually seasick people are described as being **green**, not yellow, but it's a sort of sickly green-yellow that might be described either way.

Comment: Thank you so much, randomhead!  Your kind answer is always very  helpful.

Comment: Once, on a rough crossing from Newhaven to Dieppe, just about everyone in sight, including my whole family, save for me, got violently seasick. I found I was rather hungry and enjoyed fish and chips. My family all seemed to blame me for this.